# Get notified about new iOS releases

Tags: ios

Is there a way to get notified about upcoming iOS final releases, maybe a week or a few days before the actual release happens? For major releases, there seems to be a GM seed before the actual release happens, but for minor releases (like the upcoming iOS 9.3), there are just a bunch of beta builds. I'd like to skip testing my app with all of the beta builds and just focus on the most recent one, a few days before the release actually happens.

Comment: Other than [real-time releases](https://twitter.com/iosreleases), no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Historically, Apple has not pre-announced specific release dates for updates or major releases. This is likely done to allow Apple to better deal with last minute problems.

Your best option is to follow [Apple Developer News](https://developer.apple.com/news/). An [RSS feed](https://developer.apple.com/news/rss/news.rss) is available for this information.

Comment: Thought so. Thanks for your answer, subscribed to the feed :)

Comment: Sadly tracking Apple's releases is a cost of being a developer. Avoiding the latest frameworks and *strictly* following expected API use will save most minor updates causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here is a RSS link that only contains release news:
http://developer.apple.com/news/releases/rss/releases.rss